# Core Google Map API for J2ME

Tags: google-maps, java-me

I am using http url to show map in J2ME application but it takes more time as it draws image on each refresh. since internet speed is bit slow in GPRS.

Is there any core Google Map API for J2ME??

Is com.jappit.midmaps.googlemaps.GoogleMaps is Authorized Google Map Library for J2ME Application??

Waiting for your reply.

Regards,

Parmanand

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a core Google Map API for J2ME.  No, the Jappit library is not an official authorised product, though it was a good attempt a mapping library based on the technology available at the time.

The reason the update of the map is so **slow** in the Jappit library, is that the underlying **static** mapping service behind it is not well suited to refreshing and updating a **dynamic** map.

**Every** time the map is shifted or updated, an image the size of the screen is downloaded leading to a large amount of data traffic.  A better solution can be found in using a map tile service, implement aggressive image caching and adding overlay objects on top of it. Basically doing everything to avoid downloading more images.

So in summary use a web service like the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/), if all you need is a **single** map image. Use a dedicated Java ME mapping library such as  the [HERE Maps API for Java ME](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/HERE_Maps_Java_ME) if you want a responsive dynamic map.

As a notice of affiliation, I should mention that I do work for Nokia.